# rails4 + bootstrap displays the error as "variable @zindex-modal-background is undefined"

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootswatch

I'm trying to make the project that use bootstrap on rails4.1.6.

Here is gemfile:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootswatch-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
gem 'twitter-bootswatch-rails-helpers'
```

`$ bundle install` was successful.

and settings of bootswatch

```
$ rails g bootswatch:install cerulean
$ rails g bootswatch:import cerulean
$ rails g bootswatch:layout cerulean
```

app/assets/stylesheet/application.css

```
*= require cerulean/loader
*= require cerulean/bootswatch
```

app/assets/javascript/application.js

```
//= require cerulean/loader
//= require cerulean/bootswatch
```

but `$ rails s` and when I viewed the site , appears the following error:

```
variable @zindex-modal-background is undefined
 (in /Users/ko2ic/sample/app/assets/stylesheets/cerulean/loader.css.less)
```

How do you solve it doing?

Comment: Add the contents of `/Users/ko2ic/sample/app/assets/stylesheets/cerulean/loader.css.less` to your question.

Comment: Or google the issue. https://github.com/scottvrosenthal/twitter-bootswatch-rails/issues/30 . Seems @zindex-modal-background was dropped from bootstrap and this is causing the issue but adding this variable back in should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was resolved by adding the next code:

assets/stylesheets/cerulean/variables.less

```
@zindex-modal-background: 0;
```

reference: 
http://github.com/scottvrosenthal/twitter-bootswatch-rails/issues/30